# grep lines that start with a specific string

Tags: regex, string, bash, awk, grep

I want to find all the lines in a file that start with a specific string. The problem is, I don't know what's in the string beforehand. The value is stored in a variable.

The naïve solution would be the following:

```
grep "^${my_string}" file.txt;
```

Because if the Bash variable `my_string` contains ANY regular expression special characters, `grep` will cry, and everyone will have a bad day.

You don't want to make `grep` cry, do you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `awk` instead of `grep` for non-regex search using `index` function:

```
awk -v s="$my_string" 'index($0, s) == 1' file
```

`index($0, s) == 1` ensures search string is found only at start.

Comment: what if I want to find the string at the beginning of the line, but I need the whole line to be printed?

Comment: That's what this command does. Test it out

Comment: Found my mistake!

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by *if the Bash variable `my_string` contains ANY regular expression special characters, `grep` will cry*

```
$ cat file
crying now
no cry
$ var="n.*"
$ echo "$var"
n.*
$ grep "^$var" file
no cry
```

Now that @anubhava spoon-fed me the problem (thank you sir), using `grep` for the job does seem to need at least two `grep`s and since you want to `grep` the regex characters literally, use `-F` in the latter (or `fgrep`):

```
$ cat file
OMG it’s full of 
*s
$ var="*"
$ grep "^.\{"${#var}"\}" file|grep -F "$var"
*s
```

`${#var}` returns `var` length in Bash and that amount of chars we extract from the beginning of file to be examined with the latter `grep`.

(Quote from [*2001*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_(film)))

Comment: Problem is that using `-F` we cannot force `grep` to find match only at start of line.

Comment: @anubhava Oh yeah, that is true. Good morning.